# I need it to show Yes automatically when the status is completed

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, modern-experience

[image]

I need it to show YES automatically when the status is completed and remaining as NO if is still in progress. Please share a code to make this happen.

See the images attached. I have also tried several codes but not working (Attached is the list of codes):

[image]

Comment: What are the different choices available for "Task Status" column? You want to Yes if task status is equal to Completed or are there any other conditions to make "Complete Ontime" column to "Yes" (maybe due date)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're creating a calculated column, [Completed Ontime], and wanted to know the formula to show "Yes" when [Task Status]="Completed", "No" for all other statuses

Here is the formula:

```
=IF([Task Status]="Completed","Yes","No")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need "Priority" to be part of the conditions?

If no, use the formula [Matiur Rahman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/86762/matiur-rahman) shared, that would be enough for validation.

If yes, add the additional conditions using **AND** or **OR** function to the IF function.

Example:

```
=IF([Task Status]="Completed",IF([Priority]="High","Yes"),"No")
```

Reference: [Examples of common formulas in lists.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)